# Create a spesific subclass object from user input

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

First post so guess I am still kinda noob.

Setting: I am making a text-based RPG and this question is about the character creation process.

I have an super class (individual) with several subclasses (Cleric, Fighter, Mage for example). I know how to get conditional user input (like "do you want to be a Cleric, Fighter or Mage") and the character creation is working fine (I can make a mage subclass with correct variables, and the subclass methods overrides the superclass methods).

What I do NOT know, is how to make a constructor that makes a user-input subclass (specified below).

The methods I DO know if include "`if, if else`" statements like - "

```
If( user_input.equals("Cleric"))
 {
   Cleric userName = new Cleric(userName);
 }
```

and so on, but I kinda want to avoid it.

I also want to avoid all "instanceOf" statements later on, so I want main to know what kind of subClass "player" is.

So, in point:

What I REALLY want is a few lines in main like this:

```
String playername = getInput("Please give your name"); (I have this)
Class/String/whatever subClass = constructorClass();
```

Where a class 
 `Public ClassInstance constructorClass()` does something like

```
{
    // String classType = userInput("Do you want to be a", option1, option2,option3,option4);}
```

return classType AS A CLASS TYPE to main

And back in main, a call like this is done:

```
user_inputted_class player = new user_inputted_class(playername);
```

Thank you

Comment: Search for "Factory design pattern" (eg. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

Comment: You should really think twice before using reflection to this. What happens for example, if the user types "Clerc" instead of "Cleric"? Reflection will throw some ugly exception. So, you will have to check the "input" strings for correctness (to reject invalid input). But - that means you have to code `if (input.equals("Cleric"))` statements anyway.

Comment: I based my question on factory pattern. What my problem is is that I do not know how to tell main what sort of class to call for without having a whole lot of "ifs" in main. The "factory" of sorts does all the checks (for example, make sure the player cannot choose a class that does not exist). Very simply, I ask the player to choose a class with a input method that will not return anything but legal classes. But given that string (correct subclass name) I still does not know how to make main construct that given subclass. All subclasses have their own constructor of course.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using enum's for each class option in a switch and used a playerinput(option1, option2, option3,option4) for input.

Its kinda like "ifs" but looks much neater in main.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Class` class.

A fast example :

```
Class<Cleric> clazz = Cleric.class;
// Later
// I assume you have only one constructor
Cleric userName = clazz.getConstructors()[0].newInstance("hello");
```

You'll have some exceptions to manage but no big deal.

More information `Class` here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Here a better example for your spefic case :

```
// XXXX is the super class of Cleric and Warrior.
Map<String, Class<? extends XXXX>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("cleric", Cleric.class);
map.put("warrior", Warrior.class);
// ...

XXXX player = map.get(nameOfSubclass).getConstructors()[0].newInstance("playername");
```

You'll have some exception to manage. And you should test the `nameOfSubclass` to be sure that the entry exists in the map.

Comment: In your example, you are calling `newInstance()`for Cleric.class; and you assume that the returned value is a **string**?!

Comment: In the first example of Allan Karseth, the code was just `userName = new Cleric();`, so yes i assumed that Cleric is a subclass of String.

Comment: You should read more carefully: `Cleric userName = new Cleric(userName);`
Besides: the String class is final; so there can't be subclasses of it.

Comment: No, I do not assume Cleric is a subclass of string, I specified it was a subclass of "Individual", all the player classes are. Each subclass (Fighter, Cleric) have their own constructor with 1 String argument.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to formulate my problem is: How do I get main to construct an object given this info: "String nameOfSubclass"  and "String playername" when the constructors are on this form: "nameOfSubclass player = new nameOfSubclass(playername);. This given that I do not want ugly if-statements in main.

Comment: Magus: Wouldn't this make "player" an "Individual" object of runtype "Cleric" or a real "Cleric" object? And if the first one, does for example a player.attack(); call call get the "Individual" version or the "Cleric" version of the .attack() method? (given that Cleric version has override). Last question i guess, what sort of exceptions?

Comment: You should read some documentation about polymorphism and Object Oriented Programmation (OOP).